# is it possible to reorder the sidebar?

Tags: tools

I have a few add ons and each one has its own sidebar tab I use some of this addons more then others is there a way to arrange them at all as I have not found out how to do so so far I am refering to the N shortcut (Windows system)

Comment: You can use this addon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DwMwso9MR8